# File web service architecture

Tags: web-services, file-io, soa, fileserver

I need to implement a web service which could provide requested files to other internal applications or components running on different networks. Files are dispersed across different servers in different locations and can be big as few gigabytes.

I am thinking to create a RESTful web service which will have implementation to discover the file, redirect the HTTP request to another web service on different location and send the file via HTTP.

**Is it a good idea to send the file via HTTP or will it be better for the web service to copy the file to the location where requester component could access it?**

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem with distributing large files over HTTP is that you will come across all sorts of limits that prevent it. As a simple example, WCF allows you to configure maximum payload size but you can only configure it up to 2 GB. You will likely run across issues like this in all layers of your stack. I doubt any of them are insurmountable (to work around the above limitation you can stream chunks of the file, rather than the entire file, although that [introduces it's own problems](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yassers/archive/2006/01/21/515887.aspx)), but you will likely have lots of timeouts and random failures, which are fixed by tweaking the configuration of this or that service or client.

Also, when dealing with large files, you have to carefully consider how you deal with the inevitable failures during transfer (e.g. the network drops out). Depending on the specific technologies you use, they may have some "resume" functionality, but you will want to be sure this is reliable before committing to it.

One possibility would be to do what [Facebook does when distributing large binaries](http://arstechnica.com/business/2012/04/exclusive-a-behind-the-scenes-look-at-facebook-release-engineering/) - use BitTorrent. So, your web-service serves a torrent of the file, not the file itself. The big advantages of BitTorrent are it is *very* robust, and can scale well. It's worth considering, but it will depend a lot on your environment and specific workload.

Comment: BitTorrent option is interesting, I will check it!

Answer (score 1):

If the files you are going to serve, do not change often or do not change at all, you could use many strategies, since the one advised by RB, or use pure HTTP which supports partial data operations, see [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.16).

But depending on your usage scenario, I would also suggest you to take a look at the [Amazon Web Services - S3 (Simple Storage Service)](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/s3), which probably does already what you are trying to do, it's cheap and have high availability.